# clear form fields after submit

Tags: 7, forms

im trying to clear the form fields after submitting (with ajax)
right now after submitting the fields remain filled, how can I do this?

at the bottom of the script you can see my attempt.
I think I should be able to do this with unset form, another option would be jquery. Been trying this for a while now, any ideas?

```
<?php

function social_links_form($form, &$form_state) {
$form['#suffix'] = '<script type="text/javascript">'
                 . 'jQuery(\'input#edit-url\').focus();'
                 . '</script>';

$form['box'] = array(
    '#type'         => 'markup',
    '#prefix'       => '<div id="box">',
    '#suffix'       => '</div>',
);
$form['url'] = array(
    '#type'         => 'textfield',
    '#required'     => TRUE,
    '#description'  => "Please enter your url name.",
    '#ajax'         => array(
    'wrapper'       => 'box',
    'name'          => 'url',
    ),
);
$form['title'] = array(
    '#type'         => 'textfield',
    '#required'     => TRUE, 
    '#description'  => "Please enter your title.",
    '#ajax'         => array(
    'wrapper'       => 'box',
    'name'          => 'title',
    ),
);
$form['icon'] = array(
    '#type'         => 'hidden',
    '#required'     => TRUE, 
    '#description'  => "Icon path",
    '#ajax'         => array(
    'wrapper'       => 'box',
    'name'          => 'icon1',
    ),
);

$form['file'] = array( 
    '#title'        => t('Upload image'),
    '#type'         => 'file',
    '#description'  => t('Images must be one of jpg, bmp, gif or png formats.'),
    '#ajax'         => array(
    'wrapper'       => 'box',
    'name'          => 'icon2',
    ),
); 

$form['submit'] = array(
    '#type'         => 'submit',
    '#ajax'         => array(
    'callback'      => 'social_links_insert',
    'wrapper'       => 'box',
    'name'          => 'submit1',
    'effect'        => 'fade',
    ),
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
);

return $form;
}

// save form values to database
function social_links_insert($form, $form_state){

  // first handle the image upload
  $file = file_save_upload('file', array(
  'file_validate_is_image' => array(), 
  'file_validate_extensions' => array('png gif jpg jpeg'), 
  ));

  if ($file) {
    if ($file = file_move($file, 'public://')){
      $form_state['storage']['file'] = $file;
    }
    else {
      form_set_error('file', t('Failed to write the uploaded file the site\'s file folder.'));
    }
  }
  else {
    form_set_error('file', t('No file was uploaded.'));
  }
  $file = $form_state['storage']['file'];
  unset($form_state['storage']['file']);
  $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
  file_save($file);

  // display success message
  $element = $form['box'];
  $element['#markup'] = "
  <p style='font-weight: 700; color: green;'>Social link succesfully submitted</p>
  <b>URL:</b> {$form_state['values']['url']} & 
  <b>Title:</b> {$form_state['values']['title']} &
  <b>Icon:</b> {$file->filename}
  ";

  // save form values
  db_insert('social_links') ->fields(array(
  'url' => $form_state['input']['url'],
  'title' => $form_state['input']['title'],
  'icon' => $file->filename,
  'created' => date('c'),
  ))
  ->execute();

    return $element;

  // reset the form
  $form_state = form_state_defaults();
}
```

**EDIT**
I've got this on top of my admin.inc file. I think I should continue in this fashion. (because that piece of code does work)

```
 $form['#suffix'] = '<script type="text/javascript">'
                 . 'jQuery(\'input#edit-url\').focus(); '
                 . '</script>';
```

Can anyone assist me with implementing a form clear function inside the above piece of code? To be honest im quite disappointed drupal made using jquery so hard :(

**EDIT II**

second attempt:

```
$form['#suffix'] = '<script type="text/javascript">'
             . 'jQuery(\'input#edit-url\').focus(); '
             . 'jQuery(\'input[type=text]\' , "form#social-links-form").each(function(){jQuery(this).val("")});'
             . '</script>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(function ($) {
Drupal.behaviors.yourmodulename = {
    attach: function(context) {

     setTimeout(function (){
$(".button").click(function(){
    $("input[type=text]" , context).each(
        function(){$(this).val("")});
        }
        )}, 1000);
}
}
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: This will work however a better way would be to have this script run only on ajax success, which will require a bit of tweak IMO.

Comment: thanks for you answer minty, sadly, its not working. JS console says: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;  I dont see any mistakes..

Comment: TRy this :: `(function ($) {
Drupal.behaviors.yourmodulename = {
    attach: function(context) {

    var t = setTimeout(
$(".form-submit").click(function(){
    $("input[type=text]" , context).each(
        function(){ $(this).val("")})
        }
        ), 1000);
}
}
})(jQuery);`

Comment: I had to change it to this: (function ($) { Drupal.behaviors.social_links = { 
 attach: function(context) { var t = setTimeout( $("#edit-submit").click(function(){ 
  $("input[type=text]" , context).each( function(){ $(this).val("")}) } ), 1000);  } } }); (jQuery); now it doesn't throw any errors. However, the form is not being cleared :( I made sure the script is included

Comment: Ok You need to debug that step by step..cuz I cant tell you how things are structured...so do this first `jQuery("#edit-submit").click(function(e){ 
e.preventDefault(); console.log(e)
})` in your chrome browser console tab.

Comment: Minty, I've edited my post, please read :)

Comment: Cool, so it works now?

Comment: no :( I've got that focus field working. I think if I add the clear form correctly, I should get it working.

Comment: You are almost done. Now just stuff in the javascript that I wrote in my first answer right next to your's. In my code, you can see that you actually loop over all the input types that you want to target and go to each of that and apply an empty jquery value function 'val('')'

Comment: please see edit II, still not working. Do you see anything wrong with it?

Comment: Just check it on your console to see exactly what code works. If it works on console then it will definitely work henceforth. Also I think you need to escape quotation mark, just like you did to other selectors. And I am talking about val(\'\') or something on similar lines. You can even add a break point to your console and see what javascript code is being run.

Comment: Check this link http://jsfiddle.net/y9tP2/

Answer (score 3):

Try add this code to you submit callback:

```
function social_links_insert($form, $form_state){
  /*your code goes here*/

  $form_state['input'] = array();
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}
```

Also remove "return $element;" from submit callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a simple jquery callback to ajax response. So if your response is successful then, do this

```
jQuery("input[type=text]" , "form#yourformid").each(function(){jQuery(this).val("")});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer minty, In the above script, where should I put that line of code?

Comment: You can create a new js file in your module. And add this into your new js file (function () { Drupal.behaviors.yourmodulename= function (context) {jQuery("input[type=text]" , "form#yourformid").each(function(){jQuery(this).val("")});}}(jQuery)

Comment: @Minty That's Drupal 6 style JS code, it's slightly different for Drupal 7...http://drupal.org/node/756722#behaviors

Comment: Yes, I rewrote the answer as its not formatted correctly and I pressed enter mistakenly without completing the answer. Sorry about that